# Click Imageview and reply textview within a ListView ListItem and get the position in android

Tags: android

1. I want click event replyTextview and HeartImageview
2. Get Position each click of listview
3. go to from arrayadapter to other activity using intent

[image]

4.Deaclare listview in mainactivity.java

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Postion no." +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

This is array Adapter class

```
    public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> implements OnClickListener {
        ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        int Resource;
        ViewHolder holder;
        int count=0;

        public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Resource = resource;
            actorList = objects;

        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // convert view = design
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
                holder.ivheart = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_likeheart);
                holder.tvadd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_add);
                holder.tvreply=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_reply);
                holder.tvreplyadd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_replyadd);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_userpic);
                holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
                holder.tvDOB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
                holder.tvCountry = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
                holder.ivheart.setOnClickListener(this);
                holder.tvreply.setOnClickListener(this);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
            holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
            holder.tvDOB.setText("B'day: " + actorList.get(position).getDob());
            holder.tvCountry.setText(actorList.get(position).getCountry());
            return v;

        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView imageview;
            public TextView tvName;
            public TextView tvDOB;
            public TextView tvCountry;
            public ImageView ivheart;
            public TextView tvadd;
            public TextView tvreply;
            public TextView tvreplyadd;



        }



    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_likeheart:

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
         case R.id.tv_reply:

            //not working settext here
            //holder.tvadd.setText(count++);
            // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello" +count++, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             //Intent i=new Intent(ActorAdapter.this, ReplyActivity.class);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
Instead using list View’s onItemClick use convert-view on-click in adapter.

```
View v = convertView;

v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String id = actorList.get(position).getID();
                    String name = actorList.get(position).getName();
                    // Do what you want to do there. 
                }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: only get o and 1 position in  toast..I want click at 3 position and get 3 in click event in toast

Comment: Then may be size of your list is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Jawed, you are implementing the OnClickListener but you should use OnItemClickListener.

See the example code below:

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] strings = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    for (int i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
        arrayList.add(i, strings[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            Object item = list.getItemAtPosition(i);
            intent.putExtra("title", item.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This code are working.